# How can I programmatically determine if the installed SQL Server is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: c#, sql-server, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to programmatically determine if an installed instance of SQL Server (2005-2012) is 32 or 64 bit in C#. I've looked through the registry and have not found anything and I don't want to base it off whether it is installed in Program Files (x86) since they may have installed it elsewhere. Is there any where else I can look?

Edit: I won't know if I'm able to connect to the instance, so running a query won't always be possible.

Thanks

Comment: You can try sqlcmd utility. Here is some info https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2478/connecting-to-sql-server-using-sqlcmd-utility/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file properties for the instance you want to look at.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

The file description will indicate if it's 64 bit.

**"SQL Server Windows NT - 64 bit"**

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will be the best solution for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Open a SQL Command to the instance and run the below. If you are looking for a file based approach. It is a little different.

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

This will tell you what you need to know. An example output would be

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015
>   12:32:14      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the specify that I may not be able to connect to the instance, so I won't always be able to run that query. Thanks, though

Comment: @T.Dingess That's OK, but you are able to get to the file system?

Comment: Yeah, I can get the sql path from registry, so if there is a file somewhere I can check, then that should work.